# MFC - How to update edit box on runtime? (C++)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC program (game) which shows the score to the player on an edit box, I created a variable name m_score and I would like to update it every time a specific function is called. So that's easy, ++m_score. But how to I update the edit box itself?
Thanks!

Comment: With `CEdit::SetWindowText()` (inherited from `CWnd`)?

Comment: You should consider using a static control especially if the user is not allowed to change the value.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and get a copy of Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X). Don't touch MFC until you are **intimately** familiar with the Windows API. Once that's done, get Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950), if you decide to use MFC. Skipping either resource won't get you anywhere.

Comment: @IInspectable I know, I wish I had the time.

Answer (score 7):

The quick solution is to call `SetWindowText` ie.:

```
CString s;
s.Format(_T("%d"), m_score);
m_Edit.SetWindowText(s);
```

other solution is [DDX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x.aspx), so inside your void CGameDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX), add:

```
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_score); // here I assume IDC_EDIT1 is your editbox resorce id
```

now, after changing m_score call `UpdateData(FALSE);` to put m_score data into editbox;

Comment: I'm trying to use the DDX solution. Where do I call UpdateData(false)? I can't call it right after updating m_score because it's on a different function. Sorry but I'm fairly new at MFC

Comment: @Gil there is no way around, you must somehow call it after updating m_score, if this is really too much trouble then you might setup a timer which will update score every one second.

Comment: Actually if score is updated frequently, ie. every 200 ms, then timer is not that bad.

Comment: I'll rephrase: How do I call UpdateData(false)? When I just type it after ++m_score the program (obviously) freezes. So I guess there's some syntax I am missing here.

Comment: why obviously? make sure it is called on main thread and it should work.

Comment: Okay so what am I missing here? I've got an edit box called IDC_EDIT1 and {DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_score);}. I am updating m_score when the time is right and right after I call UpdateData(FALSE) and then the program freezes.

Comment: @Gil its really hard to tell whats wrong, maybe you are calling it from some loop, if I were you I would start with new project created with template and add a new EditBox with DDX enabled. Then compare differences with your current project. Now I can only suggest to ditch DDX and use SetWindowText, get your control with GetDlgControl(IDC_EDIT1).